# Cannot compare two identical strings in PHP?

Tags: php, wordpress

I've been stuck for 6 hours on this one piece of code. What am I doing wrong?

I cannot seem to be able to compare the value of two strings  **the_title()** and either just normal string directly in the IF statement or the same string from a different variable. That IF statement just doesn't work. I tried both with ==, === and with strcmp() but nothing, it just refuses to admit that both strings are indeed identical (I've printed them out several times and they match). Any thoughts?

```
<?php

    $args = array( 'post_type' => 'team', 'showposts' => -1 );

    $items = new WP_Query( $args ); 

    while ($items->have_posts()) : $items->the_post();
        $title = the_title(); // one of the titles in the while loop is indeed "Jon Snow"
        $comp = 'Jon Snow';

        if ( $title === $comp ){
          echo 'Success!';
        }
    endwhile;  
    wp_reset_query(); 
?>
```

Oh and every time IF statement doesn't work, the system just prints out all the **the_title()** values in the while loop.

Comment: If you printed them out in a browser then remember that the browser will remove extraneous whitespace. Also, are you sure there are no extra spaces at the being, in the middle or at the end of the title?

Comment: The correct WP function to use in this situation is get_the_title() which returns and does not echo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Oh and every time IF statement doesn't work, the system just prints
>   out all the the_title() values in the while loop.

You've answer in your own question. [the_title()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_title) by default prints the title of the post. To compare the title your first have to save it in variable and then compare.

**the_title()** accepts 3 parameters and 3rd parameter(FALSE) is to get the title as return value instead of just printing it. 3rd parameter is TRUE by default and it prints the title on page.

This is how you can do it.

```
<?php $posttitle=the_title( '', '', FALSE); ?>
```